# getting strange SecurityException: READ_SECRET_CONTACTS on Sharp devices

Tags: android, android-securityexception

I'm readingcontacts as per the Android documentation

Works ok on all devices, but seems like the app crashes on some or all Sharp Android devices with a SecurityException:

```
java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: reading com.android.providers.contacts.SecretContactsProvider uri content://jp.co.sharp.android.security.secretcontacts/secret_contacts_settings from pid=7530, uid=10252 requires jp.co.sharp.android.contacts.permission.READ_SECRET_CONTACTS, or grantUriPermission()
       at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1435)
       at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:185)
       at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionWithOperationApplicationExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:160)
       at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.applyBatch(ContentProviderNative.java:461)
       at android.content.ContentProviderClient.applyBatch(ContentProviderClient.java:225)
       at android.content.ContentResolver.applyBatch(ContentResolver.java:903)
```

I've tried adding such a permission to my manifest, but it's not helping either.

Has anyone encounter this issue? is there a way to pass this security check?

Comment: Seems like sharp messed up when making their android flavor, the permission is probably signature or signatureOrSystem level, and that's why you can't grant it. Only thing you can do is report it to them.